# What do the numbers on the Users page mean?

Tags: support, reputation

On the user search page of the Math SE site (shown by the picture below), there are numbers that appear below each username. At first I thought these were reputation points of each user, but apparently they are not. I have no idea what these numbers mean, however...

[image]

Comment: The tag *support* is more appropriate when you ask a question about how the site works, rather than initiate discussion about how it should work.

Comment: If you mouse over the number and hover for a moment, it tells you "Reputation this month: 5109" and so on.

Answer (score 6):

These are reputation changes for the current month. Select `all` on the right to see total reputation values.

Comment: Whoa, someone is in the first row without being an expert in either *homework* or *calculus*.

Comment: Second row has only one calculus expert, and no homework experts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just commented on what I saw on the screenshot. I don't look at those rows myself; in fact I hide the green number thing in the top bar with userCSS.

Comment: I'm colorblind, so you'll have to do much much better than "the green number thing". Because I have no idea what that would be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's a rectangle with + symbol next to a number, which has been linked to dopamine rush in certain users. As opposed to the neighboring rectangle without + symbol, which has been linked to snarky comment exchanges.

Comment: Ah. That green thing.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier How can we use userCSS to hide the all those +5's and +10's? They are a distraction for me as well. I think I found the code on this page (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261022/can-we-specify-which-on-site-notifications-we-get-and-when-they-get-displayed) but where would we paste it (e.g. somewhere in our accounts or our Internet browsers)? (Please keep in mind that I have no familiarity with userCSS or its usage.)

Comment: @glace Search for <the name of your browser> + user + css. For example, if the browser is Chrome, you will find extensions Stylebot and Stylish, both of which manage user's CSS rules.